# Partially disable autoformatting in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-7, autoformatting

I'm starting to use netbeans and leaving eclipse (aptana in my case).

For long, I've been using tags like `@format:off` and `@format:on` to disable/enable auto-formatting of some parts in a PHP file.

Is there any way to do the same on netbeans? some annotation, some special comment or something?

Examples, I suppose I have this horrible code:

```
class A {
public function foo() {
$aux = array("key1" => 1,"key2" => "omega"
);
//@format:off
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($aux);die;
//@format:on
return $aux;}}
```

And when I press the magic short-cut (Alt+Shift+F), I want to get this:

```
class A {
    public function foo() {
        $aux = array(
                "key1" => 1,
                "key2" => "omega"
        );
        //@format:off
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($aux);die;
        //@format:on
        return $aux;
    }
}
```

If look closely, the debugging code remains on the left side.